# How to know what is the logical error?

Tags: java, arrays, operators

**Made a program to find cube of individual integers given in a line separated by space.**

This is the program. It have some logical error. It is working for any case where input is character.

```
class Cube{

    void process(){
        int i=0,sum=0,j;
        int cube;
        int ar[]=new int[100];
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            if(scan.hasNextInt()){
               ar[i]=scan.nextInt();
               i++;
            }
            else{
                scan.next();
            }
        }     
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            cube=ar[j]*ar[j]*ar[j];
            sum=sum+cube;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }  
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Cube obj=new Cube();
        obj.process();
    }
}
```

Input is given through online compiler: 1 2 3 4 5 or of any length

Comment: What's your output and what do you expect?

Comment: the answer to your actuall question is `debugging`

Comment: @JohannisK input is given through an online compiler's input panel . I compiled and got correct output. but the test cases cannot be passed

Comment: You can use Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input is in single line as `1 2 3 4 5`  you can use this to take input as string and then parse it to String array.

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
String line[] = scan.nextLine().split(" "); //split by space
for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){
int val = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
int cube = val*val*val;
}
```